# Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory - Legacy Limitations

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We experience issues with OAuth token that expires earlier than default Refresh Token Max Age. [Exceptions](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.md#exceptions) table specify 12 hours for users that are federated. What if the federation doesn't use AADConnect (aka AADSync) and use no password for authentication but a different authentication factors from federated system?
We are using Pure-Cloud AzureAD solution without on-premisses sync (AADConnect).

Are theses Exceptions only for default (built-in) Azure AD Policies or these also apply to all custom Azure AD Policies?

Thanks

P.S. We talk about 30k users who have to reauthenticate more often than they should using standard OAuth implementation.

Comment: What did you meant default Azure AD Policies and custom Azure AD policies? The default value listed in the document is enforced when there is no policy has been assigned to the service principal, the organization, or the application object, the default values is enforced. Please refer [Policy evaluation and prioritization](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.md#exceptions).

Comment: And since that the document only mention the federate scenario, based on my understanding, **Refresh Token Max Age** works no matter you sync the account/password to cloud or not.

Comment: @FeiXue, [default Azure AD Policy](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.md#configurable-token-lifetime-properties) values for OAuth token define default values (see Table).
You mean if we set own Policy the [Exceptions Table](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.md#exceptions) won't apply?